# Strange behaviour in Spyder 3.6 AttributeError: module 'EBL' has no attribute 'EBL'

Tags: python, module, attributes, spyder, python.net

Atm I am struggeling with an issue, that drives me crazy. Here is my problem:

### Problem:

I am trying to use a dll (called EBL.dll) to connect with a hardware device in order to send and receive commands and measurements. A collegue of mine supported me and at his working station with the same setup (operating system, versions of python and spyder) everything works perfectly fine. However in my case spyder always drops the error message

> AttributeError: module 'EBL' has no attribute 'EBL'

However this happens always when I push the play button or run the file in spyder. I checked the attributes which the instance of the module EBL includes and compared this to what a collegue of mine gets with the same setup, the same packages and the same code. This is what I get:

```
dir(EBL)
Out[18]: ['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

and this is what my collegue gets:

```
dir(EBL)
Out[3]:
['CheckDeviceNetConfig',
 'ClearDeviceDiagnosticMemory',
 'ConfigureCommandValueGenerator',
 'ConfigureValveTestSignalgenerator',
 'Connect',
 'DeviceInfo',
 'DeviceOscilloscope',
 'Disconnect',
 'Eal',
 'EasyStartUp',
 'Enable',
 'Equals',
 'Finalize',
 'GetHashCode',
 'GetInterfaceInfo',
 'GetType',
 'InitializeForValveMessurement',
 'IsEasyStartUpOn',
 'IsEnableOn',
 'IsParameterizationLevelOn',
 'LoadParameterfile',
 'LogFilePath',
 'MemberwiseClone',
 'Overloads',
 'ParameterBitCheck',
 'ParameterBitReset',
 'ParameterBitSet',
 'ParameterizationLevel',
 'Password',
 'PowerOff',
 'PowerOn',
 'ReadDataTo16BitArray',
 'ReadListElement',
 'ReadListUInt16',
 'ReadListUInt32',
 'ReferenceEquals',
 'ResetPassword',
 'SaveAllParametersToFile',
 'SaveParametersToFile',
 'SearchForDevices',
 'SetDeviceNetworkConfig',
 'SetDeviceOperatingHours',
 'SetDeviceTime',
 'SetDeviceToOpenLoop',
 'SetMasterCommunicationSercos',
 'SetPassword',
 'SetValveController',
 'SwitchDevicesToTCPIP',
 'ToString',
 'ValueGeneratorEnable',
 'WaitForCommandStatus',
 'WaitForParameterBits',
 'WriteData',
 'WriteListDouble',
 'WriteListUInt16',
 'WriteListUInt32',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__overloads__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'get_DeviceInfo',
 'get_DeviceOscilloscope',
 'get_Eal',
 'get_LogFilePath',
 'get_Password',
 'get_ValueGeneratorEnable',
 'log',
 'set_LogFilePath',
 'set_Password',
 'set_ValueGeneratorEnable']
```

As you see somehow with the following minimal example we both used, I am not able to load the attributes.

### What I tried

I already tried a bunch of things like:

1. Creating a new environment with the minimum of packages including pythonnet
2. Installing pythonnet in different ways via

> conda install -n  -c conda-forge pythonnet

> pip install pythonnet

> pip3 install pythonnet

btw. I know that conda install should be prefered to pip ;)

3. loading the module as instance with pickle from a pickle file my collegue created
4. copying and loading his working environment as yml

### Minimal working example

```
import clr
from os import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/daten")
clr.AddReference('EBL')
import EBL as myebl 
import time
# from EBL import EBL

# Creates EAL connnection object
device = myebl.EBL()
```

And btw.: Yes, all files are in the same folder and the current working directory is also set ;).

This issue is somewhat different to the issue addressed in other posts, since here I don't try to load a module from a py file or a class, but from a dll. The former one works perfectly fine.

So the questions I need to answer are:

**1. Why does python/spyder/anaconda not load the entire module?
2. How can I make it load the entire module?**

Thank you already in advance and sorry for the quite long text ;)

Comment: In between. I recently found out, that by splitting the code in cells and excecuting each cell with [Shift]+[Enter] all attributes in the module EBL are loaded. However if I run the program as usual with the play button, I get the error mentioned above. If I do so, I first have to restart spyder in order to be able to use the module again. Then a %reset also doesnt work anymore. Thats annoying since I neither can use the run button nor work in debbuging mode.